# How to understand struct padding?

Tags: c

I studied [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), but the following experiment confused me.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct a_t {
        char aa;
    };

    struct b_t {
        int bb;
        int bbb;
    };

    struct c_t {
        struct a_t  parent_a;
        struct b_t  parent_b;
        char cc;
    };

    struct c_t c;
    printf("sizeof(a_t)=%d\n", sizeof(struct a_t));
    printf("sizeof(b_t)=%d\n", sizeof(struct b_t));
    printf("c address=%p\n", &c);
    printf("c's parent_a=%p\n", &(c.parent_a));
    printf("c's parent_b=%p\n", &(c.parent_b));
    printf("c + sizeof(a_t)=%p\n", (struct b_t *)(&c + sizeof(struct a_t)));

    return 0;
}
```

Here is output:

```
sizeof(a_t)=1
sizeof(b_t)=8
c address=0x7fff9bca7680
c's parent_a=0x7fff9bca7680
c's parent_b=0x7fff9bca7684
c + sizeof(a_t)=0x7fff9bca7690
```

The last 3 lines in the output are surprises:

1. `c's parent_a=0x7fff9bca7680`, this is expected. parent_a address equals to struct variable c's address.
2. `c's parent_b=0x7fff9bca7684`, this is a surprise, parent_b size is 8 bytes, how come its address is not multiple of 8?
3. `c + sizeof(a_t)=0x7fff9bca7690`, this is a surprise, this is 16 bytes beyond c's address! `struct a_t` is size 1 byte, I had expected it is 0x7fff9bca7681.

Could you shed light?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic increments the address by the size of the pointed to type. Including padding, the size of `c_t` is 16, and because the size of `a_t` is 1, the address is incremented by 16 bytes.

Comment: (2) The size of a struct  `b_t` may be 8 bytes, but the alignment requirement is met for all members within on a 4-byte boundary. There is no reason to pad out between `parent_a` and `parent_b` to 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 2. `c_t` only has to be 4-byte-aligned due to the size of its largest member.

Answer 3.  Due to pointer math, `&c` is a pointer to a `c_t` which has size 16, so adding one to that pointer adds 16 bytes to the address.

The size of `c_t` is 16 because `a_t` is size 1, 3 bytes of padding to align `b_t`, size of b_t is 8 (total 12), then `char cc` is size 1, but needs 3 bytes of padding at the end (total 16) so if `c_t` is used in an array it will still have all its members aligned on 4-byte boundaries (the size of the largest member).

Comment: The wording is a bit misleading. The *size* of largest member is not what defines the required alignment. On a 32 bit CPU an `uint128_t` won't need 128bit alignment but only 32 bit. At the same time a smaller `double` might require 64 bit alignment.

Comment: Yes there is an upper limit to alignment. Compilers have options to set the upper limit, so padding can be eliminated if the upper limit is set to 1.